# Webpack aliases appear to not work in .js files on a CRA application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am using a `webpack.config.js` on my CRA project, that looks like this:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'components': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components'),
      'containers': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/containers'),
      'images': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/images'),
      'styles': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/styles'),
      'utils': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/utils'),
    },
    extensions: ['.jsx', '.js', '.scss', '.json'],
  },
};
```

so that I can use a project structure like this:

```
src
  components
    ...
  containers
    c1
      c1.jsx
      c1.scss
    c2
      c2.jsx
      c2.scss
    index.js
  images
    ...
  styles
    ...
  utils
    ...
```

Where `containers` is a folder inside the `src` folder, `c1` and `c2` are folders that contain `.jsx` and `.scss` files for components (or containers in this example), and `index.js` is a file that successfully exports all the containers within the `containers` folder to use in other components like this:

`import { c1 } from 'containers';`

The code above works in all `.jsx` files I've created, but at this point in the project I have created a file in `utils` called `routes.js`, which needs to import a container. However, using the line above I get the following error:

`expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports`

The code points to the places where I have to use the container, so I thought of changing the line in the file to relative importing:

`import { c1 } from '../containers/c1/c1';`

And that works. But (correct me if I'm wrong) shouldn't the `.js` extension declared in `webpack.config.js` enable the aliases to work on my file? Is there something am I missing that I should add to enable the aliases in files other than `.jsx`? Please let me know, and thanks for any help in advance.

**EDIT:** The containers (like `c1.jsx`) are declared like this:

```
export function c1() {
  return (
    <div>example</div>
  );
}
```

Then the `index.js` inside the `containers` folder looks like this:

```
export { c1 } from ‘./c1/c1’;
export { c2 } from ‘./c2/c2’;
```

**EDIT #2:** It seems that changing the code to this `import { c1 } from 'containers/c1/c1';` makes it work, so the real problem is that `routes.js` doesn’t recognize the index file

Comment: You need to show your `containers/index` file.. There should be the exports related to `c1`, `c2`....etc..

Comment: @Panther please look at the edit